# Onde ficam os arquivos do aplicativo no emulador do Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, sqlite

Eu estou usando o emulador do Android Studio para testar uma aplicação, com isso estou usando o SQLite para salvar alguns dados, eu queira saber onde ficam os arquivos do aplicativo e onde o SQLite grava, seria só questão de conhecimento mesmo.

EDIT:

Estou tentando acessar pelo adb e está dando permission denied, segue:

c:\Android\SDK\platform-tools>adb devices
List of devices attached
emulator-5554   device

c:\Android\SDK\platform-tools>adb -s emulator-5554 shell
generic_x86:/ $ chmod
chmod: Need 2 arguments

1|generic_x86:/ $ chmod 777 /data
chmod: chmod '/data' to 40777: Permission denied

1|generic_x86:/ $ chmod 777 /data/data
chmod: chmod '/data/data' to 40777: Permission denied

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O Android irá salvar os arquivos do SQLite em um diretório chamado "databases" dentro do package do app no sistema operacional.

Para acessar esse diretório de um modo fácil, abra o Android Studio e encontra a opção "Device File Explorer". No meu Android Studio versão 3.3.1 ele está sendo exibido no canto inferior direito da IDE, caso não apareça no seu poderá pesquisar pela opção diretamente na barra na parte superior que irá encontrá-la.

Após acessar o Device File Explorer, será mostrado a lista de dispositivos conectados dentro de um combobox (pode alternar entre os dispositivos selecionando o desejado). Logo abaixo é listado uma grande quantidade de arquivos e diretórios que são os arquivos que o Android possui dentro dele.

Encontre nesta lista o diretório `data` e abra-o. Será mostrado uma outra lista com outros diretórios, encontre novamente um com o nome `data` (é isso mesmo, são 2 `data`, um dentro do outro). Ao entrar no segundo diretório `data` procure pelo pacote do seu app (para encontrar o nome dele abra o `Android Manifest` do app e logo no início dele encontre o `package`, o nome lá é o que precisa encontrar). O último passo é abrir o diretório do pacote do seu app e acessar a pasta `databases`, dentro dela é onde está o arquivo do banco do seu aplicativo.

**Detalhe**: O arquivo do banco é criado somente quando o app tentar fazer acesso a ele. Não basta somente abrir o aplicativo, o banco só será criado quando realmente for solicitado acesso a ele. Caso na abertura do app não for feita nenhuma chamada ao banco ele não sera criado, no momento de realizar alguma consulta ou inserção ou qualquer ação é que isso acontece.

Utilizando o emulador é possível inclusive extrair esse banco facilmente utilizando um comando do CLI "adb". (Caso esteja com 2 ou mais dispositivos conectados será necessário especificar para qual deles o comando será aplicado. Recomento assim que mantenha apenas 1 emulador aberto e não tenha nenhum dispositivo real conectado ao PC nesse momento para que possa compreender como o comando funciona, posteriormente poderá pesquisar os métodos de direcionar o comando mesmo com mais dispositivos conectados)

**Sintaxe:**

```
adb pull /data/data/<package da aplicacao>/databases/<nome do banco> <local de destino>
```

**Exemplo:**

```
adb pull /data/data/com.exemple.app/databases/banco.db %USERPROFILE%\Desktop\
```

Comment: Esta pasta "data" que fica dentro do Android\SDK\ está vazia, é dela que você está falando?

Comment: tentei dar "pull" pelo Monitor e ele me entrega uma pasta vazia também

Comment: @IgorBoldt editei a resposta com mais detalhes para que fique mais compreensível. A resposta compreende os passos para encontrar o arquivo utilizando o explorador de arquivos do Android Studio. O comando pull é feito seguindo esse caminho e também descrevi na resposta algumas dicas para que funcione corretamente. Caso não tenha ficado claro ainda pode especificar o que tentou fazer para que analise e possa esclarecer mais algum detalhe.

Answer (score 0):

Procura o Menu Lateral "Device File Explorer", no meu caso ele esta no canto Direito;
Depois na árvore que abrir vá em :
Data\Data\br.com.seuprojeto\database\seubanco.db

Comment: Eu usei o "monitor.exe" e ele não consegue abrir a pasta "data" que fica dentro do com.'meuapp', eu clico pra abrir mas não vai...

Comment: não conheço outro método